# How to open Play Market on Google Play Services page?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-play-services

I have the app where I need to notify the user that he needs to update Google play services and redirect him to an Play Market on Play Services app page. Can you help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and this code in your activity

```
   // Check status of Google Play Services
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

// Check Google Play Service Available
try {
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices).show();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
}
```